Prove that the equation of a circle is unique
The equation of a circle with center $(a,b)$ and radius $r$ is $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$.
Thus, geometrically, we can see that the following claim is true.

(*) If, for every $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$, we have $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$ if and only if $(x-c)^2+(y-d)^2=t^2$,
then $a=c,b=d,r=t$ (with the assumption that $r,t>0$).

Is there an algebraic proof of (*), in other words, without appealing to Euclidean geometry?

Expand the Squares to get :
$x^2-2ax+a^2+y^2-2by+b^2=r^2$
$x^2-2cx+c^2+y^2-2dy+d^2=t^2$
Subtract , then arrange the terms to get :
$Ax+By+C=0$
When that is true for $(x_1,y_1)$ , $(x_2,y_1)$ , then :
$Ax_1+By_1+C=0$
$Ax_2+By_1+C=0$
Subtract , we will get :
$A(x_1-x_2)=0$
Hence , $A=0$ hence $a=c$
Likewise for $(x_1,y_1)$ , $(x_1,y_2)$ , we will get :
$B=0$ hence $b=d$
Eventually , we will get $r=t$

Why not just compare corresponding terms after expanding the squares?

Here the corresponding terms may match , though not in the general Case. Specifically , two Equations $A_1x+B_1y=C_1$ , $A_2x+B_2y=C_2$ may represent the same line though $A_1=A_2$ may be false , @ТymaGaidash , which occurs when $B_1=B_2$ is also false. Parametric Cases give more such concerns.

Doing the change of coordinates $x'=x-a$, $y'=y-b$, the equations of the circle are
$$(x')^2+(y')^2=r^2,$$
$$(x'+a-c)^2+(y'+b-d)^2=t^2.$$
Therefore, it suffices to treat the case where $a=b=0$, and we only have to show that $c=d=0$ and $r=t$.
According to the first equation, the points $\left(\frac{r}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$ and $\left(-\frac{r}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$ are in the circle. Since they also satisfy the second equation, the equalities
$$\left(\frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}-c\right)^2+\left(\frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}-d\right)^2 = t^2,$$
$$\left(-\frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}-c\right)^2+\left(\frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}-d\right)^2 = t^2,$$
hold.
Hence we deduce
$$\left(\frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}-c\right)^2 = \left(-\frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}-c\right)^2.$$
There are two possibilities:
$$\frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}-c = -\frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}-c \quad \text{ or } \quad \frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}-c = \frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}+c.$$
Since $r > 0$, the first case is not possible. Therefore we conclude that
$$\frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}-c = \frac{r}{\sqrt{2}}+c,$$
and hence, that $c=0$.
A similar argument shows that $d = 0$, and hence it easily follows that $r=t$.
